# Display ArrayList content in Thymeleaf loop

Tags: java, html, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

i have problem with display my items from database. I assign my item object to ArrayList and want to display it in html file, every time when I try display it, i have Whitelabel Error Page.
When i display this code below its worked but iteration not.

HTML:

```
<span th:text="${item.get(0).getItemName()}"></span>
```

^ working

```
<tr th:each="person, state : ${item}" class="row" th:classappend="${state.odd} ? 'odd-row' : 'even-row'">
    <td th:utext="${item.getItemName()}">Full Name</td>
</tr>
```

^ Not working

Java:

```
List<item> item = new ArrayList<>();
itemRepository.findAll().forEach(item::add);

List<item> findList = new ArrayList<item>();

for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++) {
    if(item.get(i).getWhoAdd().equals(isExist.getId())){
        findList.add(item.get(i));
    }
}
model.addAttribute("item",findList);
return "item";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code sample you have shown as not working, try using the following

```
<td th:text="${person.getItemName()}">Full Name</td>
```